# GtkTextBuffer "mark_set" signal fires callback 3-4 times for Arrow-Keys or Mouse-Click

Tags: c, gtk2

I am attempting to use the `'mark_set'` signal to update the `row:col` values within my *GtkTextBuffer*. For testing I have a simple setup with the *textview* inside a *scrolled window* inside a *window*, e.g.:

```
window
  scrolled window
    textview
```

I use a structure to hold the various values for my application, for example:

```
typedef struct {
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *view;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer;
    GtkTextMark *cursor;
    gint line;
    gint col;
    gint winwidth;
    gint winheight;
} context;
```

I am trying to update the current `line` and `col` values in the instance of the struct used with my application to track the *line* and *column* positions within the buffer. In the *create_window* function I initialize the values for `context *app;` (defined in `main()`) and connect the `'mark_set'` signal to the `on_mark_set()` callback, passing the instance of the struct as data to the callback. e.g.:

```
g_signal_connect (app->buffer, "mark_set",
                  G_CALLBACK (on_mark_set), app);
```

The `on_mark_set()` callback (with *g_print* for example and debug purposes) is:

```
void on_mark_set (GtkTextBuffer *buffer, context *app)
{
    GtkTextIter iter;

    app->cursor = gtk_text_buffer_get_insert (buffer);

    gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_mark (buffer, &iter, app->cursor);

    app->line = gtk_text_iter_get_line (&iter);
    app->col = gtk_text_iter_get_line_offset (&iter);

    g_print (" line: %3d col: %d\n", app->line + 1, app->col + 1);
}
```

The values for `app->line` and `app->col` are correctly set (only once) following each keypress where *input* is provided to the buffer. e.g. inputting `'abc'` into the textview results in:

```
$ ./bin/text_mcve
 line:   1 col: 2
 line:   1 col: 3
 line:   1 col: 4
```

However, when I use the `arrow keys` to move the input cursor or use the `mouse` to reposition it, the callback *tripple*-fires or *quadruple*-fires. e.g. pressing the <kbd>left-arrow</kbd> to backup one position results in the following:

```
line:   1 col: 3
line:   1 col: 3
line:   1 col: 3
```

Repositioning to the end by clicking the mouse results in a *quadruple*-fire of the callback:

```
line:   1 col: 4
line:   1 col: 4
line:   1 col: 4
line:   1 col: 4
```

How can I limit the the execution of the `on_mark_set()` callback to a single call regardless of whether there is data being entered or if cursor is being moved with the arrow-keys or mouse? Given that `'mark_set'` is the only signal that can cover input->cursor position handling regardless whether to positioning input comes from a *keypress* or *mouse-click*. The goal is to utilize the `'mark_set'` signal to handle all `row:col` updating, but I must find a way to prevent the callback from being triggered more than once for each keypress or mouse-click event.

When using the `'key_press_event'` with the *textview* widget, you can pass create a *gboolean* callback and pass a *GdkEventKey* and handle the `event->keyval` manually to handle cursor repositioning with the keyboard (including the arrow-keys), and by `return` tell the default input handlers that no further action need be taken for any given keypress, but that does not, and cannot work with mouse-clicks. So if I can do it all through the `'mark_set'` signal, that would be my choice.

Is there some way I can do the same with the `'mark_set'` event to insure the `on_mark_set()` callback is only executed once regardless of keypress or mouse click? I have posted to the *gtk-app-devel-list*, but have not received a response. S.O. is probably a bit more active on gtk topics than the gtk-list itself. Any help with this conundrum will be greatly appreciated.

**MCVE for Testing**

A *MCVE* for testing purposes is provided below. Compile with `gcc -o progname progname.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0)`

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

typedef struct {
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *view;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer;
    GtkTextMark *cursor;
    gint line;
    gint col;
    gint winwidth;
    gint winheight;
} context;

GtkWidget *create_window (context *app);
void on_window_destroy (GtkWidget *widget, context *app);
void on_mark_set (GtkTextBuffer *buffer, context *app);

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    context *app = NULL;
    app = g_slice_new (context);

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    if ((app->window = create_window (app))) {
        gtk_widget_show (app->window);
        gtk_main();
    }
    else
        g_print ("\nerror: create_window returned NULL\n\n");

    g_slice_free (context, app);

    return 0;
}

GtkWidget *create_window (context *app)
{
    GtkWidget *scrolled_window;
    GtkWidget *vbox;
    PangoFontDescription *font_desc;

    app->winwidth = 500;    /* window width x height */
    app->winheight = 350;

    app->line = 0;          /* initialize beginning pos line/col  */
    app->col = 0;

    app->window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (app->window), "mark_set MCVE");
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (app->window),
                                 app->winwidth, app->winheight);
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (app->window), 5);

    vbox = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 0);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (app->window), vbox);

    app->buffer = gtk_text_buffer_new (NULL);

    app->view = gtk_text_view_new_with_buffer (app->buffer);
    gtk_text_view_set_wrap_mode (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (app->view), GTK_WRAP_WORD);
    gtk_text_view_set_left_margin (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (app->view), 10);
    font_desc = pango_font_description_from_string ("DejaVu Sans Mono 8");
    gtk_widget_modify_font (app->view, font_desc);
    pango_font_description_free (font_desc);

    scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new (NULL, NULL);
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scrolled_window),
                                    GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC,
                                    GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);

    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (scrolled_window),  app->view);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), scrolled_window, TRUE, TRUE, 5);

    g_signal_connect (app->window, "destroy",
                      G_CALLBACK (on_window_destroy), app);
    g_signal_connect (app->buffer, "mark_set",
                      G_CALLBACK (on_mark_set), app);

    gtk_widget_show (app->view);
    gtk_widget_show (scrolled_window);
    gtk_widget_show (vbox);

    return app->window;
}

void on_window_destroy (GtkWidget *widget, context *app)
{
    GtkTextIter start, end;
    gtk_text_buffer_get_bounds (app->buffer, &start, &end);
    g_print ("Exiting... buffer contained:\n%s\n",
             gtk_text_buffer_get_text (app->buffer, &start, &end, FALSE));
    gtk_main_quit ();
    if (widget) {}
}

void on_mark_set (GtkTextBuffer *buffer, context *app)
{
    GtkTextIter iter;

    app->cursor = gtk_text_buffer_get_insert (buffer);

    gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_mark (buffer, &iter, app->cursor);

    app->line = gtk_text_iter_get_line (&iter);
    app->col = gtk_text_iter_get_line_offset (&iter);

    g_print (" line: %3d col: %d\n", app->line + 1, app->col + 1);
}
```

Thanks again for any suggestions or help. **note:** this code is part of a gtk+2 application, but can be compiled with gtk+3 as well with minimal deprecation warnings.

---

**Solution**

Since a solution to this problem is not readily available on the web by normal search means, I'll post the solution I arrived at after being pointed in the right direction by the answer below. The suggestion in the answer, after changing the callback prototype, was to compare the mark properties each time the `mark_set` signal was generated and to discard all `mark_set` calls that do not meet a required property. While that approach is not workable due to there being no usable *unique* property to identify (any or all of the 3 name possibilities: `null`, `insert` or `selection_bound` can be generated for any given insert cursor movement), that did provide the spark for a way to distinguish between *new* and *current* `mark_set` signals.

The key was to initialize and store the current `line:col` positions within the buffer on buffer creation. This can be done in the `create_window()` function:

```
GtkTextIter iterfirst;
...
app->cursor = gtk_text_buffer_get_insert (app->buffer);
gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_mark (app->buffer, &iterfirst, app->cursor);
app->line = gtk_text_iter_get_line (&iterfirst);
app->col = gtk_text_iter_get_line_offset (&iterfirst);
```

Knowing the *current* `line:col` values, you can then compare with the *new* `line:col` values that would be generated based on the `GtkTextIter *iter` value passed as a parameter to the `on_mark_set()` callback. That provided an easy comparison of *current* to *new* values, allowing you to respond to only the `mark_set` signal that caused a change in the `line:col` values:

```
void on_mark_set (GtkTextBuffer *buffer, GtkTextIter *iter,
                GtkTextMark *mark, context *app)
{
    gint line, col;

    line = gtk_text_iter_get_line (iter);
    col = gtk_text_iter_get_line_offset (iter);

    if (line == app->line && col == app->col) return;

    app->line = line;
    app->col = col;

    g_print (" line: %3d col: %d\n", app->line + 1, app->col + 1);

    if (mark) {}
}
```

(**note:** the debug `g_print` statements is left above to provide context for the output below) Further note, a comparison between `mark` and `gtk_text_buffer_get_insert (buffer)` could not be made due to `gtk_text_buffer_get_insert (buffer)` only returning matching values when *arrow-key* or *mouse-click* inputs were made. (the comparison fails for normal text input).

Now when repeating the same sequence of events noted in the original question (e.g. enter `'abc'`, then backup 1 with the <kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd>, then left-click at the end to reposition cursor) shows that the `on_mark_set` now properly responds to only updated `line:col` values:

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/text_mcve
 line:   1 col: 2
 line:   1 col: 3
 line:   1 col: 4
 line:   1 col: 3
 line:   1 col: 4
Exiting... buffer contained:
abc
```

---

**Multiple Marks at each `iter` Location in No Particular Order**

In order to leave this questions as a good reference, if not a good solution, I'll include the results of further debugging into this topic. There is a complete dearth of information on this particular topic to be found anywhere else.

Further debugging shows why there is difficulty in this area and why a simple comparison between `mark` and `gtk_text_buffer_get_insert (buffer)` cannot reliably be used alone to determine whether to respond to a `"mark_set"` signal or not. Why?

Each time the `"mark_set"` signal is generated, there can be multiple `marks` at any given `iter` *location*. In the case of normal input (e.g. `'a'`, `'b'`, etc...) the `mark` passed to the `on_mark_set()` callback is not necessarily the `"insert"` mark, but is apparently simply the last of the marks present at that iter *location*. (In each case below an *anonymous mark*) The list of marks at any given `iter` position can be found by the `GSList` of marks returned by `gtk_text_iter_get_marks (iter)`. (**note:** the marks in the list returned are in *no particular* order -- which is probably the basis for this whole issue to begin with. See: [**gtk_text_iter_get_marks()**](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkTextIter.html#gtk-text-iter-get-marks) ) For example, you can examine the marks with the following debug code:

```
void on_mark_set (GtkTextBuffer *buffer, GtkTextIter *iter,
                GtkTextMark *mark, context *app)
{
    gint line, col;

#ifdef DEBUG
    g_print ("  mark: %p  - gtbgi (buffer): %p  mark->name: %s\n", mark, 
            gtk_text_buffer_get_insert (buffer), 
            gtk_text_mark_get_name (mark));

    GSList *marks = gtk_text_iter_get_marks (iter);
    GSList *p = marks;
    gint i = 0;
    while (p) {
        const gchar *name = gtk_text_mark_get_name (GTK_TEXT_MARK(p->data));
        g_print ("    mark[%d] : %p : %s\n", i++, GTK_TEXT_MARK(p->data), name);
        p = p->next;
    }
    g_slist_free (marks);
#endif

    line = gtk_text_iter_get_line (iter);
    col = gtk_text_iter_get_line_offset (iter);

    if (line == app->line && col == app->col) return;

    app->line = line;
    app->col = col;

#ifdef DEBUG
    g_print (" line: %3d col: %d\n\n", app->line + 1, app->col + 1);
#endif

    if (mark) {}
}
```

Compiling and then using the same (enter `'abc'`, then <kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd>, then *mouse-click* at the end) fires the `on_mark_set()` callback for each `'abc'` entered:

```
$ ./bin/text_mcve_dbg
  mark: 0x2458880  - gtbgi (buffer): 0x237d600  mark->name: (null)
    mark[0] : 0x237d600 : insert
    mark[1] : 0x237d620 : selection_bound
    mark[2] : 0x237d7a0 : gtk_drag_target
    mark[3] : 0x2458880 : (null)
 line:   1 col: 2

  mark: 0x24792c0  - gtbgi (buffer): 0x237d600  mark->name: (null)
    mark[0] : 0x237d600 : insert
    mark[1] : 0x237d620 : selection_bound
    mark[2] : 0x237d7a0 : gtk_drag_target
    mark[3] : 0x24792c0 : (null)
 line:   1 col: 3

  mark: 0x24797a0  - gtbgi (buffer): 0x237d600  mark->name: (null)
    mark[0] : 0x237d600 : insert
    mark[1] : 0x237d620 : selection_bound
    mark[2] : 0x237d7a0 : gtk_drag_target
    mark[3] : 0x24797a0 : (null)
 line:   1 col: 4
```

Examining, there are 4-marks at each `iter` location and the `mark` passed by the callback is `mark[3]` even though all 4 are actually present at the `iter` location.

When the <kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd> key is pressed, the callback fires 3 times with each of the marks present each time:

```
  mark: 0x237d600  - gtbgi (buffer): 0x237d600  mark->name: insert
    mark[0] : 0x237d600 : insert
    mark[1] : 0x237d620 : selection_bound
 line:   1 col: 3

  mark: 0x237d620  - gtbgi (buffer): 0x237d600  mark->name: selection_bound
    mark[0] : 0x237d600 : insert
    mark[1] : 0x237d620 : selection_bound
  mark: 0x2479700  - gtbgi (buffer): 0x237d600  mark->name: (null)
    mark[0] : 0x237d600 : insert
    mark[1] : 0x237d620 : selection_bound
    mark[2] : 0x2479700 : (null)
```

For the first firing of the callback, the `"insert"` mark is passed, the second firing the `"selection_bound"` mark is passed and lastly, the anonymous `'null'` marks is passed. Essentially, the callback fires once for each mark at the `iter` location when the <kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd> key is pressed.

When the mouse is clicked to position the insert point at the end of the buffer, the callback fires 4 times as follows:

```
  mark: 0x237d600  - gtbgi (buffer): 0x237d600  mark->name: insert
    mark[0] : 0x237d7a0 : gtk_drag_target
    mark[1] : 0x237d600 : insert
    mark[2] : 0x237d620 : selection_bound
 line:   1 col: 4

  mark: 0x237d620  - gtbgi (buffer): 0x237d600  mark->name: selection_bound
    mark[0] : 0x237d7a0 : gtk_drag_target
    mark[1] : 0x237d600 : insert
    mark[2] : 0x237d620 : selection_bound
  mark: 0x24792a0  - gtbgi (buffer): 0x237d600  mark->name: (null)
    mark[0] : 0x237d7a0 : gtk_drag_target
    mark[1] : 0x237d600 : insert
    mark[2] : 0x237d620 : selection_bound
    mark[3] : 0x24792a0 : (null)
  mark: 0x2479200  - gtbgi (buffer): 0x237d600  mark->name: (null)
    mark[0] : 0x237d7a0 : gtk_drag_target
    mark[1] : 0x237d600 : insert
    mark[2] : 0x237d620 : selection_bound
    mark[3] : 0x2479200 : (null)
    mark[4] : 0x24792a0 : (null)
```

where there is a `'gtk_drag_target'` mark included when the mouse is clicked, but otherwise, aside from the additional mark and additional anonymous mark, it behaves like the <kbd>Left-Arrow</kbd> key press.

So the bottom line, since the `"insert"` mark is included in every firing as one of the marks at the location, but is *Not* passed as the parameter `mark` to the callback on normal text input, then there isn't a way to prevent the callback firing multiple times in any case. The best that can be done is to efficiently determine if the callback needs to respond to a `"mark_set"` signal. In that case, checking whether the `"insert"` mark is present and whether there is any change in the `line:col` location is about as good as it gets.

The other alternative is split reponsibility for updating the `line:col` location between the `on_mark_set()` callback and an input-handler callback and to have your input-handler update `line:col` for normal text input and `on_mark_set()` only respond when the `"insert"` `mark` is passed as a parameter. However, I'm not sure that is any better a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mark_set` signal is emitted for change of *any* mark, not just the cursor position. Mouse moves probably affect the selection mark as well, which is why it appears as if you are getting multiple signals. A correct handler for the `mark-set` signal should inspect the `mark` argument and ignore the marks it doesn't care about, in this case all marks except the insertion mark as returned by `gtk_text_buffer_get_insert(buffer)`.

The last points leads to a problem in the code as originally presented. According to the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html), it should be declared as

```
void user_function (GtkTextBuffer *textbuffer, GtkTextIter *location,
                    GtkTextMark *mark, gpointer user_data)
```

...whereas your handler only accepts the buffer and the user data. Writing to the memory reserved for the `location` iterator can cause corruption in unrelated parts of the code and compound the problem.

Once the handler prototype is fixed and the non-cursor marks ignored, the multiple invocation problem should go away.

Comment: You know, I've probably spent a day on that very page and looked at that very function, but without *any* documentation on the page regarding the function use, it was unclear how it could discriminate between the key pressess and mouse-clicks. Thank you for pointing me the right direction.

Comment: I have a solution, but it does not involve comparing the *mark*-`name` property. You can't. Why? The *mark names* associated with insert cursor movements are (`null`), `insert`, and `selection_bound`. There is no *unique* mark identifiable for any given `mark_set` (e.g. you can get all 3 names for arrow-key movements and `selection_bound` plust 2-`null` for mouse movement. The only thing possible is to keep current `line:col` values and compare the new `line:col` values based on the `location` iter passed and only respond for new values. I'll add an edit to the question.

Comment: @DavidCRankin you shouldn't care about mark names, you should compare the mark object you receive as the third argument to the callback with the insertion mark, obtained by caking `gtk_text_buffer_get_insert ()`. As written, your call reacts to *all* mark changes, which is incorrect since a buffer can contain any buffer of marks unrelated to the current cursor position.

Comment: Ah, that is what I didn't know was possible given that comparing pointer values raised to possibility of re-use of a pointer causing false equality comparison. I'll go rework and test the values again. I did test the `gtk_text_mark_get_name (mark))` values (which is where I got the anonymous names used). I'll give the *mark* comparisons a try. But I must still be missing something because I would still have to compare the *mark object* within the callback. That seems like it would only save the one function call. I'll poke around a bit more, but the *current* - *new* comparison works well.

Comment: OK, now I'm confused. If I prefix the start of `on_mark_set()` with `if (mark != gtk_text_buffer_get_insert (buffer)) return;` the function only responds to `arrow-key` and `mouse-click` as normal text input does not generate an `insert` mark (only `null`). Are you suggesting something else?

Comment: @DavidCRankin A straight comparison is what I meant by "ignoring the marks it doesn't care about" - ignoring everything except the mark returned by `gtk_text_buffer_get_insert`. I'll amend the answer to be more explicit about that. Pointer reuse is not an issue since the insertion mark lives as long as the buffer. (And even if it didn't, calling `gtk_text_buffer_get_insert` in each callback invocation would still ensure that you are comparing the mark to the current insertion mark.)

Comment: I got it. I just had to get up and walk around a bit and let it sink in. You are saying, `on_mark_set()` has the responsibility to validate it is responding only to the *textview* buffer in setting the `line:col` values. Otherwise, it will respond to any `mark_set` that could be generated by *any* buffer in the code. Got it. Thanks!

Comment: What I opted for in this case, which looks to accomplish the required validation (since `app->buffer` is previously stored) is a simple comparison between `buffer` and `app->buffer` which guarantees the `mark_set` was generated by the desired buffer. (`if (buffer != app->buffer) return;`). This avoids the problem of `mark != gtk_text_buffer_get_insert (buffer)` for normal text input.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Not any buffer in the code, but any mark in the buffer. Since the signal handler is tied to a particular buffer, it should not be invoked for other buffers. If comparing `buffer` to `app->buffer` changes the behavior of the program, it might indicate a bug elsewhere in the code.

Comment: I will ultimately get this sorted out. I see the various considerations, the multiple marks in the same buffer, etc., but where this whole validation breaks down is the fact that with normal input (e.g. `'a'`, `'b'`, ...) `mark != gtk_text_buffer_get_insert (buffer)`. I dumped every mark and pointer to see what would work. When doing so, there is no relationship between `mark` and `gtk_text_buffer_get_insert (buffer)`. What am I missing in the way I am trying to make the comparison for normal text input that leaves `mark != gtk_text_buffer_get_insert (buffer)`? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Got it! Every time the `"mark_set"` signal is generated, there can be anywhere from 2-5+ marks at every iter location. You can examine with `gtk_text_iter_get_marks (iter)`. `gtk_text_buffer_get_insert (buffer)` only returns one of the many. The `mark` passed as the parameter may or may not be the `insert` mark. To do it properly, you must get the `GSList` of marks at the `iter` *location* passed and then only update `line:col` if `insert` is among the marks at that `iter` location. Sheesh, what a way to do it...